# Attribute Selection At the time of Creating Simple Product

Tags: magento-1.9, simple-product, attribute-set

I want to put attribute selection at the time of creating *Simple Product* like "Configurable Product". When admin select attributes only those attribute can be display at the time of product creation from admin panel. So how can I achieve this functionality. Any Idea and Help will be Appreciate.

I am Using Magento Version : 1.9.3.4.

Comment: You need to create different attribute sets. Based on attribute set selection while adding product, it will show only those attributes.

Comment: can you please give any type of link or code or idea for how can I do?

Comment: It is inbuilt in Magento

Comment: yes inbuilt in magento but how assign attributes for different different simple products??

Comment: means if i create one simple product and select attribute like "color" than only color attribute display and if I create another simple product and select "size" attribute than only size attribute display in product....

Comment: Not attribute. It is attribute set selection.

Comment: I create one Attribute Set based on "default" but at the time of product creation magento not ask for that Attribute set to select....

Comment: so silly mistake by me... okay kishan Thank you very much ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create different attribute sets. Based on attribute set selection while adding product, it will show only those attributes. In this way you can manage.

Comment: Hello Kishan I am not able to remove attribute which are not useful.... so can you please tell me that how can I remove attributes from attribute sets . drag is not working ,...

Comment: Which attribute you are trying to remove ?

Comment: "color" attribute which is created by me